# Using Python 3.5 to Login, Navigate, and Scrape Without Using a Browser

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm trying to scrape multiple financial websites (Wells Fargo, etc.) to pull my transaction history for data analysis purposes. I can do the scraping part once I get to the page I need; the problem I'm having is getting there. I don't know how to pass my username and password and then navigate from there. I would like to do this without actually opening a browser.

I  found Michael Foord's article "[HOWTO Fetch Internet Resources Using The urllib Package](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/urllib2.html#info-and-geturl)" and tried to adapt one of the examples to meet my needs but can't get it to work (I've tried adapting to several other search results as well). Here's my code:

```
import bs4
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

##Navigate to the website.
url = 'https://www.wellsfargo.com/'
values = {'j_username':'USERNAME', 'j_password':'PASSWORD'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('ascii')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    the_page = response.read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(the_page,"html.parser")
```

The 'j_username' and 'j_password' both come from inspecting the text boxes on the login page.

I just don't think I'm pointing to the right place or passing my credentials correctly. The URL I'm using is just the login page so is it actually logging me in? When I print the URL from response it returns https://wellsfargo.com/. If I'm ever able to successfully login, it just takes me to a summary page of my accounts. I would then need to follow another link to my checking, savings, etc.

I really appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: By looking at the form in the page what I see is it posts to https://connect.secure.wellsfargo.com/auth/login/do so that should be the url.

Comment: Thank you very much, dyeray. I believe that worked. I think my problem now is it is returning JavaScript. But I will create a separate question to tackle that beast.